# Receiving "Undefined index:port" while using tmhOAuth

Tags: php, indexing, port, undefined

I used the tutorial here:

http://140dev.com/twitter-api-programming-tutorials/hello-twitter-oauth-php/

To create a system of posting tweets to Twitter that I can use when a user posts something to their own website.  Unfortunately I can't get it to work, when I call the function I receive the error "Error: [8] Undefined index: port" which occurs on line 200 of thmOAuth.php which says "$port = @$parts['port'];"

Now as far as I can tell that means 'port' hasn't been setup anywhere but no tutorial that uses thmOAuth mentions anything about setting a port and I can't see where to set it, so anyone know what is going wrong here?

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix to this problem would be to add ':80' (if HTTP) or ':443' (if HTTPS) after the hostname in your script. Include relevant parts of your script to get more details.